# How to prove that " there is a set with no subset" is false?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question

By " subset of S " I mean here : a set that is included in set S. ( I do not restrict " subset " to " proper subset").

---

In order to show that the asssertion is false, I can think of the following :

Suppose S is a set with no subset

(1) either this is set infinite , or finite

(2) if S is infinite, there is at least one proper subset  of S such that this subset is equinumerous to S; hence, S has at least one proper subset, and, a fortiori, one subset

(3) If S is finite with cardinal n ,

- then the cardinal of P(S) is 2 to the nth power.
- in case S has no subset , the cardinal of P(S) is 0
- so n should satisfy the equation : 2 to the nth power equals  0. ( That is : 2^n=0)
- but there is no cardinal number satisfying this equation; hence an impossibility.

So, the set with no subset is neither infinite nor finite.

Consequently, there is no set with no subset.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by *subset*, consider $\emptyset$.  Either it has no subset, or it is a subset of any set

Comment: If $S$ is a set,$S$ a subset of $S$...

Comment: Every set is subset of itself : $\forall x (x \in A \to x \in A)$ is the def of $A \subseteq A$.

Comment: @GreginGre. This would have been quicker indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The empty set is a subset of every set.

The empty set is a proper subset of every set except the empty set.